# Name resolution for the name...timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded

Tags: windows-7, security, internet, dns

I am getting this message in system event during my PC startup

> Name resolution for the name `website.com` timed out after none of the
>   configured DNS servers responded.

And another same message but for different url. I checked and there is no tools or software related to website.com installed in my system actually after checking this website.com it was a forum.

Also there is no problem on my ADSL connection.

What is this message mean ? 
is some sort of hacking ? 
How to stop it ?

I am running windows 7 sp1 64bit and I use a router to connect to the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The message means that some program tried to resolve the domain name website.com, and the windows service which handles DNS queries did not get any response from the nameservers it tried.

Is it hacking? Dunno, it seems pretty benign. If website.com has a forum, perhaps your browser is trying to load a page from website.com as it restores state on startup?

How to stop it? I can't diagnose the problem with the information given. Can you resolve the name later, after startup (I'd say so, since you checked the site)? If so, I'd double check what configuration my networking setup has, and look into how the DNS servers are set (via DHCP, static addresses) and what addresses they are set to use (the home gateway, the ISP's servers, or something like OpenDNS)?

ADDED: You might try the suggestions in this Windows note: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3336.event-id-1014-microsoft-windows-dns-client.aspx

Comment: I check the system event messages before start my browser and I always find this warning message before I open my browser. I set my DNS to auto and it get the correct DNS from my ISP. is there a way to recognize what program try to connect to this url ?